# Aggregate a column sequentially based on distinct values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a standard query that looks like this:

```
Select 
X
From Y
Left Join Z
On ....
Where A and B
```

Which gives me a table as such:

```
Product Type   Product Sub-type   Process     Sequence_Number
   X                 X.1            A               1
   X                 X.1            C               2
   X                 X.1            D               3
   X                 X.2            A               1
   X                 X.2            B               2
   X                 X.2            C               3
   X                 X.2            D               4
   X                 X.2            E               5
```

I want to aggregate all of the product sub-type processes for a specific product type X to arrive at a consolidated process list such as:

```
Product Type      Process
     X              A
     X              B 
     X              C
     X              D
     X              E
```

As you can see the commonalities between sub-type processes are there, and gaps in sub-type x.1 have been filled in by x.2 processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your results can be generated by using `select distinct`:

```
select distinct product_type, process
from . . .
where . . .;
```

Comment: Is it possible to select distinct based on process but also keep the other columns as well?

Comment: @Steel . . . You should ask that as another question, with appropriate sample data and desired results.